# Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have applied the following jquery plugin for the tab user interface on my website.
https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/ui.tabs.overflowResize/master/demo/index.html

i guess it's running on the old versions of the jquery.

the website console is throwing some errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined
ui.tabs.closable.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
ui.tabs.addTab.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: no such method 'overflowResize' for tabs widget instance
```

here is the live site: http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/

can anyone tell me what is causing the error and how to fix it?

I have tried installing any other viable solution as well.

but none seems to be working.

this is the code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery( ".tabpanel" ).tabs({closable: true, addTab:true}).tabs('overflowResize')
  .find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
  distance: 10
 });
});
```

and the html:

```
<div class="window_tab">
  <div class="tabpanel">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="closable">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="closable">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" class="closable">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>
            Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>
            Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>
            Content 3</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the core function that i need is the function that i can close the tab, and reopen the specific tab when i click on the specific menu. and also they are supposed to be draggable so that i can change their order.

i'd rather expect ways to make it working, not ways to go around or giving up.

Thanks.

Comment: also i have tried this one: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-Chrome-style-Tabs-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-Chrome-Tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery-ui needs to be loaded before ui.tabs modules.  move `<script src="/xe/common/js/plugins/ui/jquery-ui.min.js?20151113203341"></script>` up inside `head` or move the rest of your scripts down bellow line 388, where jquery-ui is currently being loaded.

Comment: hi. i am seeing you again.(good to see you) um, but unfortunately, the CMS that im using generates that jquery-ui.js so i have no control over that code line. is it possible to give some sort of 'priority' on the script? if it's not, i guess i will have to move the entire body..

Comment: and what i did js that, i inserted new jquery UI cdn on the top of the page,and removed the code that was in the bottom using the chrome developer tool, but nothing seems to respond.

Comment: If you cannot move the location of the jquery UI script, you should be able to move ui.tabs scripts to be below the CMS includes.  This is preferable as including jquery-ui twice will produce conflicts.  Removing the script in developer tools will be slightly tricky, it's best to do it for real.

Comment: Okay, so, since I can't change the order of the scripts, instead, i copied all the scripts contents and pasted into the script that gets loaded right after the jquery UI library. but it seems that it's still throwing the same error. Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Comment: but what's best side of this is that,it's finally able to move the tabs around. just the close function is omitted.

Comment: i still cannot use close and open function. i contacted the original plugin writer, and he told me that i should match the order of the jquery script load, but it has not seen much progress after i have them in order. if you have any brilliant ideas how to debug this error, please let me know. (all three original tab ui js are in 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ko.js' on 389 line on the live site.

Comment: One of the scripts included inside of `<head>` is unbinding `$` from `jQuery`.  You could comment out each one, one-by-one, to find out which one is creating the problem.  If the offending script is out of your control, you can take the quick and dirty route of setting `$=jQuery` inside of `/xe/common/js/plugins/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker-ko.js` before the code for `ui.tabs.closable` begins.

Comment: You could also ask the mainainer of `ui.tabs.closable` to change `(function() {` to `(function($) {` on line 9 of ui.tabs.closable.js

Comment: I don't know how to thank enough. i thought i had all of them under function($). i appreciate your explanation. thanks.

Comment: Happy to help.  Cheers.